# problem for installing

Tags: software-installation

I extracted a zip file ( which is named ccnx-0.7.0.tar.gzip) and it extracted successfully, then for installing, i typed ./configure then make. some error messages will appear like :

```
mk dir: can not create directory 'user/local/include/ccn':permission denied
make[2]:......... error1
make[1]:***install error 1
```

and when i type `sudo make install` the following message will appear:

```
"[sudo] password for samira:"
```

i don't know what i have to enter? license or sth else.

in the readme the following is written:

```
"__BUILDING__
```

In the root directory:

```
./configure
make
```

The top-level build will compile both C and Java code, but
not Android code.  The above is sufficient to run programs
locally out of `bin/` and build apps referencing `lib/` and `include/`.

please guide me what is the error?

how can i install that?

what and where is bin?

Comment: Why are you compiling 0.7.0 when there is a newer version 0.8.2 available? http://www.ccnx.org/releases/

Comment: I want to install mini-ccnx from "https://github.com/chesteve/mn-ccnx/wiki/Installing" and the develpers used ubuntu 12.04 and CCNx 0.7.0 therefore i thought it is better i follow what they used exactly.And my installed ubuntu is 12.04 now.

Answer (score 0):

The `sudo` password is the password for your account.  So, when you first made your personal account installing Ubuntu, it asked you to make a password.  However, blanks can be done as well, or no password.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I entered my personal account and this step passed. Could you please guide me where is folder bin? I think i have to run the installed program from this folder, am i right?

Comment: According to the README, you may install it instead of running from bin. "To install to a standard location on your machine you may also use

    make install"

Comment: I entered the " make install". but i don't know ho can i run the program now.  In readme is written " 
__CCND__

All CCNx programs require that a ccnd be running:

    bin/ccndstart

To start ccnd sending output to a log file instead of the terminal,
set the `CCND_LOG` environment variable with the path of the file you
want to write.  Any existing file with that name will be overwritten.
For a listing of other environment variables that are available
(including debug message controls) run:

    bin/ccnd -h

Note that you should not ordinarily run ccnd directly, but use the ccndstart script"